# Why are my KeyCode/KeyEvent functions returning either as an invalid character or "UNDEFINDED"? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, keyevent

I am very new to JavaFX, and I am trying to work with `KeyEvents` and `KeyCodes`. Researching on how to use these properly, I looked at [this](https://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/chapter6/KeyboardEventDemo.java) webpage for how to do that.

I (somewhat) copied it's code to try to implement it to my program. Mainly what I am trying to do is to make it where when the user presses <kbd>F11</kbd>, it will go fullscreen. It works, but what I don't understand is that when it is **both** typed **and** pressed, it either returns as an unreconizable character, or it just says `UNDEFINED`.

I feel like that I will run into this problem at some point when I try to use these methods. The question is: ***Why are my KeyCode/KeyEvent functions returning either as an invalid character or "UNDEFINDED"?***

## Screenshot of the results

[image: results]

## Code

### `onKeyTyped()`

```java
static void onKeyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    String k = evt.getCharacter() ;
    System.out.println(k + " is typed") ; // What prints when it is typed

/*
    switch (k) {
        case "f" -> {
            isFullscreen = !isFullscreen ;
        }
    }
*/
}
```

### `onKeyPressed()`

```java
static void onKeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    KeyCode key = evt.getCode() ;
    System.out.println(key + " is pressed") ;
}
```

### `onKeyReleased()`

```java
static void onKeyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
    KeyCode key = evt.getCode() ;
    System.out.println(key + " is released") ;

    if (key == KeyCode.F11) {
        stage.setFullScreen(!isFullscreen) ;
    }
}
```

### Implentations to the stage

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image icon = new Image("C:\\Users\\8018156\\IdeaProjects\\Galactify\\src\\main\\java\\com\\galactify\\tiles\\gicon.png") ;

    stage = primaryStage ;
    stage.setTitle("Galactify - 0.0.1") ;
    stage.getIcons().add(icon) ;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setFullScreenExitHint("") ;

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> onKeyTyped(e)) ;
    scene.setOnKeyTyped(e -> onKeyPressed(e)) ;
    scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> onKeyReleased(e)) ;

    stage.show();
}
```

### Class attributes

```java
public static Stage stage ;
static boolean isFullscreen = false ;
static FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("demo-view.fxml")) ;
static Scene scene ;

static {
    try {
        scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 400);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the obvious typo (`setOnKeyPressed(e -> onKeyTyped(e))`, and vice-versa) and it should work as per the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html).

Comment: Don't think a function key will trigger "typed" event.  (there's no character)  The typo mentioned by @James_D is causing the odd results.

Comment: Didn't realize that I switched them. I will put that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are weird because you accidentally switched the `onKeyPressed()` and `onKeyTyped()` methods. To fix this, just simply set the `start()` method as shown:

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image icon = new Image("C:\\Users\\8018156\\IdeaProjects\\Galactify\\src\\main\\java\\com\\galactify\\tiles\\gicon.png") ;

    stage = primaryStage ;
    stage.setTitle("Galactify - 0.0.1") ;
    stage.getIcons().add(icon) ;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setFullScreenExitHint("") ;

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> onKeyPressed(e)) ; // Where you accidentally
    scene.setOnKeyTyped(e -> onKeyTyped(e)) ; // switched the methods
    scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> onKeyReleased(e)) ;

    stage.show();
}
```